# java.lang.AbstractMethodError on lint when using gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
        classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:1.6.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGP2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/espressoTest')
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-unit-test'

dependencies {
    // App
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.0.7@aar'
    compile 'com.github.flavienlaurent.datetimepicker:library:0.0.2'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu-toolbar:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.1.0'

    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    // Robolectric
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    testCompile files('lib/robolectric-2.4-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
    testCompile 'com.googlecode.catch-exception:catch-exception:1.2.0'
}

tasks.findByName("assembleDebug").dependsOn("testDebugClasses")
```

And when I'm executing:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.SourceProviderImpl.cloneProvider(SourceProviderImpl.java:56)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.JavaArtifactImpl.clone(JavaArtifactImpl.java:38)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.JavaArtifactImpl$clone.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ModelBuilder.createVariant(ModelBuilder.groovy:193)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.groovy:136)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilder$buildAll.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.createAndroidProject(Lint.groovy:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lint(Lint.groovy:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 47 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:1.6.3`. See [this issue](https://github.com/JCAndKSolutions/android-unit-test/issues/70).

Update to the latest version of this library (as well as the latest gradle tools while you're at it)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'
classpath 'com.github.jcandksolutions.gradle:android-unit-test:2.0.1'
```